# Not able to use Contact class for collision in jBox2D using Processing

Tags: java, processing, collision-detection, physics-engine, jbox2d

I am working on this project using jBox2D along with Processing(P3). While working on the collision handling, i am unable to use the "Contact" class, for getting the contact object and obtaining the fixtures.

The following is the basic structure of the code with only the necessary stuff.

```
import shiffman.box2d.*;
import org.jbox2d.collision.shapes.*;
import org.jbox2d.common.*;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.*;

Box2DProcessing mainBox2D;

void setup(){
  fullScreen();
  mainBox2D = new Box2DProcessing(this);
  mainBox2D.createWorld();
  mainBox2D.listenForCollisions();
}

void draw(){
  mainBox2D.step();
}

void beginContact(Contact c){ //this is where i am getting the error 'The class "Contact" does not exist'
}
```

I am also getting some other stuff in the error description, the screenshot of which is below.

[image]

Thank you for taking your time on reading this and helping me out.

Comment: Well described problem with minimal working code (to reproduce the issue in this case) and related informations. Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an import:

```
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.contacts.*;
```

Have fun!